# SwiftUI masking gradient with UIImage

Tags: swiftui

I want to mask a linear gradient with a Image initialized with `Image(uiImage: ...)`. This kind of masking can clearly be done with Images initialized as `systemName` but when done with a UIImage there is no "masking" performed. Note that I need to use UIImage because my intention is to use a generated qrcode as the mask.

Correctly Masked sf image:

[image]

Incorrectly masked UIImage:

[image]

Exmaple Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let string: String = "String"
    let context = CIContext()
    let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
    let size: CGFloat = 150

    func generateQRCode(string: String) -> UIImage? {
        let data = Data(string.utf8)
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
    
        if let qrCodeImage = filter.outputImage {
            if let qrCodeCGImage = self.context.createCGImage(qrCodeImage, from: qrCodeImage.extent) {
                return UIImage(cgImage: qrCodeCGImage)
            
            }
        }
    
        return nil
    }

    var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
            // sf image qr code
            GradientRectangle()
                .mask {
                    Image(systemName: "qrcode")
                        .resizable()
                 }
                .frame(width: size, height: size)
        
             // uiimage qr code
            if let image = generateQRCode(string: string) {
            
                 GradientRectangle()
                     .mask {
                        Image(uiImage: image)
                            .interpolation(.none)
                            .resizable()
                    
                    }
                    .frame(width: size, height: size)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct GradientRectangle: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [.yellow, .orange], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generated `qrCodeImage` has no transparency (as you expected) but black& white, so it is just needed to convert it additionally into mask.

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

[image: demo]

Here is fixed part of code:

```
func generateQRCode(string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = Data(string.utf8)
    filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")

    if let qrCodeImage = filter.outputImage {
        let maskFilter = CIFilter.maskToAlpha()
        maskFilter.setDefaults()
        maskFilter.setValue(qrCodeImage, forKey:"inputImage")

        if let maskImage = maskFilter.outputImage, let qrCodeCGImage = self.context.createCGImage(maskImage, from: maskImage.extent) {
            return UIImage(cgImage: qrCodeCGImage)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```